# C++ Template type deduction for temporary value

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, function-templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void wrapper(T& u)
{
    g(u);
}

class A {};

void g(const A& a) {}
int main()
{
    const A ca;
    wrapper(ca);
    wrapper(A()); // Error
}
```

Hi I have a question on why the last statement gives a compiler error.

> :18:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type
>   'A&' to an rvalue of type 'A'   wrapper(A());

I thought that the template type `T` would be deduced as `const A&` as the `ca` is also deduced as `const A&`. Why the type deduction fails in this case?

Comment: `ca` is declared as `const` then `T` is deduced as `const A`. `A()` is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that the template type T would be deduced as const A& as the ca is also deduced as const A&. Why the type deduction fails in this case?

Because that's not how the deduction rules work. They strive to deduce as much of a match to the function argument type as possible. A temporary is not necessarily const, it can just bind to a const reference.

But your function template does not accept by a const reference, instead it accepts by a non-const lvalue reference. So no `const` is gonna spring up unless the function argument is const itself (which it isn't).

The proper solution is to use a forwarding reference (an rvalue reference to a deduced template parameter):

```
template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& u)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(u));
}
```

Now `u` can bind to any object. And the types deduced will tell you the value category of the function argument, allowing you to forward that category to the function call `g(...)`, and making sure the proper overload is picked.

---

By the way, in case you are curious, if you add the const directly to the temporary type, your original code will build just fine.

```
using CA = A const;
wrapper(CA()); // Not an error anymore
```

Now `u` ends up being a `A const&` and binds to the temporary just fine. But that is just a curiosity that's unlikely to be useful in practice. Use forwarding references.

Answer (score 6):

> Why the type deduction fails in this case?

It does not fail. `T` is deduced to `A`. Therefore, the parameter `u` is of type `A&`.

The call to `wrapper()` is what actually fails, since an *rvalue* (i.e.: `A()` in this case) can't be bound to a non-`const` *lvalue reference* (i.e.: the parameter `u`).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying to convey:

*A non-`const` reference cannot bind to a temporary value because the temporary object's lifetime would have expired before the control reaches the function.*

- The variable `ca` is **not** a temporary, because it has a name that can be referred to in `main`.
- It's lifetime does not expire till the end of `main`, and so can be safely referenced from within `wrapper`.
- Template type deduction does not drop `const` since it would be a violation of `const`-correctness for `ca`.

For `wrapper(A());`, the type parameter `T` would be deduced as `A`. Since the temporary has no `const`-ness, so the parameter `u` would be deduced to a `A&`, but a since non-`const` reference cannot bind to a temporary value for the reason mentioned above, there is no `wrapper` function that is viable to be called using the argument `A()`.

Now, C++ features the extension of lifetime for a temporary object if you are only reading from it. This is the reason why `const T&` binds to temporary objects. In your case the nameless temporary object's lifetime is extended till the end of the `wrapper` function.

If you explicitly set the type parameter to be `const T&` the following:

```
template <typename T>
void wrapper(const T& u)
{
    g(u);
}

class A {};

void g(const A& a) {}

int main()
{
    const A ca;
    wrapper(ca);
    wrapper(A()); // Error no more.
}
```

would compile just fine.

---

**[C++11]**

For `wrapper(A());`, the type parameter `T` would still be deduced as `A`, and the parameter `u` would be of type `A&&`, called an rvalue reference to `A`.
Suppose we add another overload to `wrapper` so that the following:

```
template <typename T>
void wrapper(const T& u)
{
    g(u);
}
template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& u)
{
    g(u);//u is an lvalue since it has a name.
}
```

exists.

You can expect `wrapper(A());` to compile, *preferring the rvalue overload*, because the rvalue reference is an lvalue in `wrapper` as it has a name.